# How to get extra col while doing serverside processing in datatables?

Tags: datatables

I am doing server side processing of datatables and I want to show extra col merged within a col, for eg. my table looks like:

id
name
age
price

Its all working fine, but I want to display another col in the price col which I am not able to get

For example: I want it to show like

id
name
age
price cur_code

I am trying the following

```
array(
    'db'        => 'serv_price',
    'dt'        => 8,
    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
        return $d . " " . $row["serv_cur_code"];
    }
),
```

but its not displaying it, how to get cur_code extra field ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and include (a) your DataTables definition, and (b) a sample of the data you receive?

Comment: I am not sure what this means: _show extra col merged within a col_. At a guess, I think you may mean something like this: "Display two different fields or values in one column". Can you clarify? For a given row you can access all its data values using a [`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) function.